# Entity Framework Operations to SQL - Prevent Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, deadlock

I have a table in SQL Server that looks something like:

```
Col1  Id  -Int and Key    
Col2  ProductId  int    
Col3  ProductDesc   Varchar
```

Within my Silverlight app, I have two grids showing data from this table - seperated out by the ProductId - In other words, I have all the product A's in one grid and all the Product B's in the other grid.

When I select any item in either gird, I write it out to the table.  If I deselect an item from the gird, I delete the row from the talble.  Because of Silverlight's use of async calls, while one grid is busy, the user can still work with the other grid (which is what I want).  However, if the user unselects items from one grid while items are being inserted from the other, I get deadlock errors.

All of my inserts are being done after each entity has been updated and I made the call to SubmitChanges().  The deletions are being handled in a different way.  Since there is no DeleteAll in EF, I am using the Object Context's ExecuteStoreCommand() and submitting a DELETE query -  which may be were my problem is coming from.

How can I use the same table to accomplish this without getting deadlock errors?  I'm really trying to avoid creating a seperate table for each grid.

If I were to use EF to delete from my entities instead of ExecuteStoreCommand() would EF handle the deadlocks better?  It seems like a resource waist to load the table into memory, the delete each row one at a time.

EDIT:  I wanted to add that I verified that my deadlocks come when I am deleting from the talbe at the same time EF is inserting into it.

Thanks,

-Scott

Answer (score 2):

Try using isolation levels for your transactions:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = 
          new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
             new TransactionOptions() 
             {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
             }))
{
   // read only work - no locks on records. effectively SELECT xx from xxx WITH (NOLOCK)
}
```

However, AFAIK this is for scoping EF context queries. If your using `ExecuteStoreCommand` then you might have to manually put the NOLOCK hint on the query itself.

Comment: Should this be used for my delete or my insert?  Or both?

Comment: Neither. This should be used for readonly queries (SELECT). Inserts and Deletes *should* have exclusive locks.

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio (if you have access), you can monitor queries and see which ones are causing the deadlocks.

Comment: Gotcha.  One more questions:  Should the scope be defined on the client whenever creating the domain context, or should it be used within the domain service on the server?

Comment: To be honest i haven't worked much with silverlight apps. I guess it would depend if your encapsulating your data access logic behind a repository. Normally you'd new up the context (or by using the `using`) statement, and inside here you would define the transaction scope.

Answer (score 0):

Is your delete statement touching the same rows as the other operations?

If not, try adding a rowlock hint: delete from xyz with (rowlock) where ...

Comment: No, I am sure that the rows being deleted and inserted will not ever be the same.  I'll give it a shot.  That's one I've not used before.

Comment: I was hoping that would do the trick, but unfortunately I still get the deadlocks.  I'm starting to wonder if the Inserts are the problem now.  I have no idea what isolation level or locks are being placed when inserting to the table.

Comment: You could try setting the allow_row_locks and allow_page_locks options for the indexes on the table to avoid page locks. E.g.: alter index pk_some_table on some_table rebuild with (allow_row_locks=on, allow_page_locks=off)

Comment: Oh, and you could also give it a try with my profiler for entity framework - it might capture some more details about what caused the deadlock... See http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/06/entity-framework-support-in-huagati.html

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
using (var context = new XXX())   // Replace XXX with your specifics
{
  context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;"); 
  // your LINQ code here
}
```